# How to set chace expire for laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, caching

I am testing my website with `gtmetrix` and `google speed` both of them suggesting me to set expire timing on my assets including `css, javascript, images etc.` base on suggestions of those websites I added code below to my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

I tried 2 ways to add code above to my `.htaccess` file:

- first I add it to my existed code **inside** `<IfModule
  mod_rewrite.c>` result was same as before
- second i add it as separate code **out of** `<IfModule
  mod_rewrite.c>` and still i get error to set my expire timing.

### Questions

1. What Is correct way to add expire timing to my assets?
2. How do I use `cookie-free domains` on my **stylesheets** and **JavaScript** files as it remanded to me?

Comment: is mod_expires enabled?

Comment: Where should i check it?

Comment: On ubuntu and apache 2.4+ you can run `a2query -m` and check if expires is listed. If not then you can enable it using `a2enmod expires`. On other OSs you need to google it

Comment: I am using cpanel share hosting (site is online)

Comment: then I don't know how to check that. Maybe someone with more experience with cPanel can help or perhaps your shared hosting provider may answer that question.